# Fragment view inflating error: Resource is not a drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I get this error when i deploy my app on emulator with android version <= 2.3.x. All works fine on highest version:

```
    05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.widget.QuickContactBadge
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at myapp.ui.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:120)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at myapp.controls.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:895)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:469)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:441)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:422)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at myapp.controls.MyPager.setCurrentItem(MyPager.java:207)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at myapp.controls.MyPager.showLast(MyPager.java:212)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at myapp.ui.MyActivity$LoadUnreadMessagesAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MyActivity.java:377)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at myapp.ui.MyActivity$LoadUnreadMessagesAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MyActivity.java:1)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  ... 34 more
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0200bd a=-1 r=0x7f0200bd}
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.widget.QuickContactBadge.<init>(QuickContactBadge.java:92)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.widget.QuickContactBadge.<init>(QuickContactBadge.java:88)
05-22 09:33:53.641: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  ... 37 more
```

this error is referred to MyFragment line 120:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

120: View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, null);

}
```

and here there is my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myMessageMainlayout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/my_pager_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left" >
            <QuickContactBadge android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/contactBadge"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/quickcontact_badge_small"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" />

            <TextView android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/fromTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgbtn__overflow" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactBadge" android:autoLink="phone" android:ellipsize="end" android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:maxLines="2" android:paddingBottom="2dp" android:text="Text Here" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColorLink="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly" tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
            <TextView android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fromTextView" android:layout_below="@+id/fromTextView"
            android:id="@+id/timestampTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="Timestamp here"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imgbtn__overflow" style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton" android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:src="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#FFA9CC8F" android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/contentMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="8dp" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:text="Text here"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly"
                android:textColorLink="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#FFA9CC8F" android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/answerbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="4dp" >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="09" android:autoText="true" android:ems="10" android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" android:gravity="top" android:hint="@string/text_hint" android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoEnterAction" android:inputType="textShortMessage|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences" android:maxLines="4" android:minLines="2" android:nextFocusRight="@+id/send_" android:shadowColor="#000000" android:shadowDy="0.5" android:shadowRadius="0.5">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgbtn_send"
                style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentMms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mmsSubjectTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Mms subject here"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly"
                android:textColorLink="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/viewMmsButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="140dp"
                android:text="@string/button_view_mms" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentPrivacy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/viewButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button_view"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:dividerPadding="0dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="beginning" >
            <ViewSwitcher
                android:id="@+id/buttonViewSwitcher"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"
                android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out" >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ButtonLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn__close"
                        style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="@string/button_close" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn__call"
                        style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="@string/button_call" />
                    <Button android:id="@+id/btn__open" style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" android:text="@string/open_"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/UnlockButtonLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <include layout="@layout/unlock_button" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ViewSwitcher>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The layout error is referred to line #18 where i open the QuickContactBadge xml tag. How can be this possible? I have no custom style and custom views. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you forget to add `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes  for `QuickContactBadge` View in xml. do it as:

```
<QuickContactBadge 
        <!--  add height and width for View -->
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:id="@+id/contactBadge"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:background="@drawable/quickcontact_badge_small"
       android:clickable="false"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" />
```

Comment: what's QuickContactBadge ?

Comment: @blackbelt : `QuickContactBadge` is a control which introduced in Android Api level 5 you can see [QuickContactBadge](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/QuickContactBadge.html) for more info

Comment: I try to add android:layout_width and android:layout_height but same error

Comment: @ethe : after providing hight-width plz clean or build project again before running

Answer (score 0):

Is your drawable resource stored in the folder named drawable-swNNNdp ?
This kind of configuration qualifers was introduced in Android 3.2, so even if Eclipse don't show any issue, you'll get this error on lower emulator.
hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full class name in XML. It could be helpful to define `android.widget.QuickContactBadge` instead of shorthand `QuickContactBadge`:

```
<android.widget.QuickContactBadge android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/contactBadge"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/quickcontact_badge_small"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" />
```